# URL is not working in LWC which is placed on Account record lightning page

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-experience, url

I have created LWC to display third-party application page on record, it is giving me login page but after logging in it is giving error as "Sorry, we couldn’t find what you are looking for". I believe it is because of fullUrl() method in js file, not sure though because I can see values are being fetched successfully.

Error:

[image]

Please find below the code for reference:

HTML:

```
<template >
<lightning-card  title="Station A Card">
    <template if:true={record}>
        <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
            <iframe width="350" height="490" src={fullUrl}></iframe>
        </div>
    </template>
    <template if:true={error}>
        {error}
    </template>
</lightning-card>
```

.js file:

```
    import { LightningElement, api, track, wire }   from 'lwc';
import { getRecord }                            from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';

export default class StationACard extends LightningElement {

    @api recordId;
    @track record;
    @track error;

    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: ['Account.BillingStreet', 'Account.BillingCity','Account.BillingState'] })

    wiredAccount({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            this.record = data;
            this.error = undefined;
        } else if (error) {
            this.error = error;
            this.record = undefined;
        }
    }

    get Street() {
        return this.record.fields.BillingStreet.value;
    }
    get City() {
        return this.record.fields.BillingCity.value;
    }
    get State() {
        return this.record.fields.BillingState.value;
    }

    get fullUrl() {
        return `https://card.stationa.com/v1/places?theme=light&query_address={!URLENCODE(Street)},{!URLENCODE(City)},{!URLENCODE(State)}`;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not a correct format to encode url in LWC, also you are not doing string concatenation properly in `js`

Here is what it should look like

```
return 'https://card.stationa.com/v1/places?theme=light&query_address='+encodeURI(this.Street)+','+encodeURI(this.City)+','+encodeURI(this.State);
```

Comment: Thank you Nagendra, it worked as expected.